# Copy row from one table to other without copying the checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

Here is link https://jsfiddle.net/Palak_js/c8kq2q5d/4/

I am able to add row to other table but,I dont want checkbox to be copied along also when I set default checkbox to be checked it does not works fine. Is there any way I can remove checkbox from other table and by default set checkbox to checked and row gets deleted when checkbox is unchecked

```js
$("#vergeTable input:checkbox.chkclass").click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).closest("tr").clone().appendTo("#vergeTable2");
  } else {
    var index = $(this).closest("tr").attr("data-index");
    var findRow = $("#vergeTable2 tr[data-index='" + index + "']");
    findRow.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="pure-table dataTable table-bordered vergeTable rowClick" id="vergeTable" role="grid">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th align="left" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Navn</th>
      <th align="left" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Mandat</th>
      <th align="left" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Status</th>
      <th align="left" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Regnskapsplikt</th>
      <th align="left" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Dato startet</th>
      <th align="left" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Dato til</th>
      <th align="left" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Velg</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-index="1">
      <td>Alfred Psa Asker</td>
      <td>Ivareta personens interesser innenfor det personlige og økonomiske området</td>
      <td>
        Tidligere
      </td>
      <td>Ordinær</td>
      <td>10.07.2013</td>
      <td>01.10.2016</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="chkclass" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr data-index="2">
      <td>Testfirst Testlast</td>
      <td>Ivareta personens interesser innenfor det personlige og økonomiske området</td>
      <td>
        Nåværende
      </td>
      <td>Ordinær</td>
      <td>05.12.2016</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="chkclass" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>-----
<br>

<table class="pure-table dataTable table-bordered selectedVergeTable rowClick" id="vergeTable2" role="grid">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th align="left" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Navn</th>
      <th align="left" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Mandat</th>
      <th align="left" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Status</th>
      <th align="left" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Regnskapsplikt</th>
      <th align="left" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Dato startet</th>
      <th align="left" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Dato til</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should bind the `change` event instead of `click` and you need to remove it from clone object. `change()` or `trigger('change')` can be used to trigger the event handler on page load.

```
//Bind change event
$("#vergeTable input:checkbox.chkclass").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        //Cache cloned object in a variable
        var clone = $(this).closest("tr").clone();
        //Remove checkbox
        clone.find(':checkbox').remove()
            //Append it
        clone.appendTo("#vergeTable2");
    } else {
        var index = $(this).closest("tr").attr("data-index");
        var findRow = $("#vergeTable2 tr[data-index='" + index + "']");
        findRow.remove();
    }
})
.change(); //<==== Trigger on page load
```

```js
$("#vergeTable input:checkbox.chkclass").change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    //Cache cloned object in a variable
    var clone = $(this).closest("tr").clone();
    //Remove checkbox
    clone.find(':checkbox').remove()
      //Append it
    clone.appendTo("#vergeTable2");
  } else {
    var index = $(this).closest("tr").attr("data-index");
    var findRow = $("#vergeTable2 tr[data-index='" + index + "']");
    findRow.remove();
  }
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="pure-table dataTable table-bordered vergeTable rowClick" id="vergeTable" role="grid">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th align="left" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Navn</th>
      <th align="left" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Mandat</th>
      <th align="left" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Status</th>
      <th align="left" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Regnskapsplikt</th>
      <th align="left" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Dato startet</th>
      <th align="left" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Dato til</th>
      <th align="left" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Velg</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-index="1">
      <td>Alfred Psa Asker</td>
      <td>Ivareta personens interesser innenfor det personlige og økonomiske området</td>
      <td>
        Tidligere
      </td>
      <td>Ordinær</td>
      <td>10.07.2013</td>
      <td>01.10.2016</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="chkclass" checked />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr data-index="2">
      <td>Testfirst Testlast</td>
      <td>Ivareta personens interesser innenfor det personlige og økonomiske området</td>
      <td>
        Nåværende
      </td>
      <td>Ordinær</td>
      <td>05.12.2016</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="chkclass" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>-----
<br>

<table class="pure-table dataTable table-bordered selectedVergeTable rowClick" id="vergeTable2" role="grid">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th align="left" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Navn</th>
      <th align="left" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Mandat</th>
      <th align="left" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Status</th>
      <th align="left" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Regnskapsplikt</th>
      <th align="left" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Dato startet</th>
      <th align="left" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Dato til</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/c8kq2q5d/6/)

Comment: checkbox is  by default checked still row is not cloned to other table when running for first time

Comment: Thank you so much, I got it :)

Comment: I am not able to remove in original code which is  given below as there is no input type as checkbox                               <td class="contentCenter"><form:checkbox path="regnskap.regnskapVerge[${loop.index}].velgVerge"  id="regnskapVerge${loop.index}" cssClass="transForm1Dot5 valgtVerge" /></td>

Comment: @DeadEnd, Are you using `Spring MVC`? then you are asking question guy

Comment: Yes, when I look from front end through fire bug I am getting index for rows but in code it is not accepting @Satpal